Can you use latexmk on Overleaf to generate multiple latex files?
I'm trying to shuffle multiple choice exams and choices. I've got python code but want to be able to run it on Overleaf.com. Tried with latexmkrc file below but couldn't generate multiple outputs. You can find tex files and python script at https://github.com/gokcemay/ExamShuffle
It is likely possible using command line but Overleaf doesn't have that. can `latexmk` process multiple files in parallel?
# latexmkrc configuration file for Overleaf

# Add a custom dependency to run the Python script
add_cus_dep('py', 'tex', 0, 'run_python');

sub run_python {
    my $base = shift;
    return system("python3 generate_exams.py") == 0;
}

# Specify the XeLaTeX command
$xelatex = 'xelatex %O %S';

# Ensure that the Python script is run before processing the LaTeX document
if ( -e 'generate_exams.py' ) {
    system('python3 generate_exams.py');
}

